# Haskell App Crash: Handling Native Exceptions

Tags: haskell

I have a haskell package which contains native code as well. However, I get exceptions, (and sometimes segfaults) as I interface through FFI.

Is it possible to handle native exceptions on the haskell side. I tried using catch/catchIOError in the some cases without any success.

In this case, I would also like to like to debug **only** the native code. How can I use native debuggers with Haskell/FFI?

Sometimes, segfaults may occur in the C code. Being able to debug this code would help a lot.

Comment: A segfault isn't something you can catch and recover from. Much like the Windows "blue screen of death", it means your application pretty much _must_ be shut down now. So no, there's no way to catch such a thing and carry on running.

Comment: I changed the question to make it more specific (and hopefully clear). I am more interested in finding the issues the native part, and also if I am doing anything wrong especially marshalling the values.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid You can recover from a segfault, the question is just what to do.  E.g., I've implemented a garbage collector that used segfault for the read&write barrier.

Comment: This is probably going to make me sound stupid, but... what is a "native exception"?

Comment: @DanielWagner, here I mean code outside haskell runtime. I kind of loosely borrowed the term from managed/unmanaged code in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

If you think the error is in a component in C, just use `gdb`. You should be able to set breakpoint in your C code and step into it. Compile your code and simply run `gdb dist/build/myprogram/myprogram` (or wherever it is).

Also you could have a look at `valgrind` for detecting thinks such as allocated memory not freed.